# Поиск и уведомление на чужом сайте

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно что бы приходили звуковое уведомление о написанном сообщение в чате, а именно "Жалоба" [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

тут работает на данное слово, но оно приходит только один раз, подскажите как можно "зациклить" что бы при каждом сообщении "жалоба" звуковое уведомление приходило

```js
if (document.querySelector('.abuse'))
{
  var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://noisefx.ru/noise_base/zvon/01070.mp3');
audioElement.play(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://noisefx.ru/noise_base/zvon/01070.mp3');
document.querySelector('.abuse').onclick = () => {
    audioElement.currentTime = 0;
    audioElement.play();
}
 // Лично мне нравится такой синтаксис:
let audioElement = new Audio("http://noisefx.ru/noise_base/zvon/01070.mp3");
document.querySelector('.abuse').onclick = () => {
    audioElement.currentTime = 0;
    audioElement.play();
}
```